# Error al colocar el Onclick en button (Error CS1061)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

El problema es que actualmente en la pantalla poseo 2 botones, uno cerra sesión y el otro registra un usuario, ambos funcionan bien.
Al momento de agregar otro botón para editar no da problemas, pero al momento de colocarle el Onclick se daña la página diciendo que es el error CS1061.
[image: Aquì observamos que está bien la imagen]

Aquí está el ejemplo, el botón cae bien si alguna función (Editar)
Al dar doble click en el botón en el modo diseñador, se genera lo siguiente en su respectivo aspx.cs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en su respectivo normal aparece lo comùn: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, está igual que los botones anteriores, sin embargo al momento de ejecutarlo, sucede lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ante ello, las soluciones que he leído son con colocar protected (El cuál ya está) o generar esos dandole doble click al botón (Lo cuál realicé) También al tratar de limpiar o recompilar el código, se genera un error que no tiene que ver con el tema.

Espero haya sido claro, de antemano, muchas gracias por leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Harry el problema es debido a que a veces visual studio se tranca, en la solución dale click derecho > Recompilar Solución y debería solucionarse.

A veces se cuelga el codigo behind y no encuentra la referencia. Coméntame que tal te fue;Saludos

[image: Recompilar Visual studio]

Comment: Recuerda el evento tiene que ser asi 
protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Aqui el codigo
    }

Comment: Efectivamente al recomplilarlo me solucionó todo, muchas gracias.

Comment: No es nada, me agrada haberte ayudado